# Custom notification at user date and time

Tags: android, notifications, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I have to show notification to user at user's selected time and date and my code is below.

```
public static void setAlarm(Context context, long id, int rYear, int rMonth, int rDay, int rHour, int rMinute) {
    if (Share.wantReminder) {
        Share.wantReminder = false;

        Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(rYear, rMonth, rDay, rHour, rMinute);


        Calendar calendar1 = new GregorianCalendar();
        calendar1.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calendar1.set(Calendar.YEAR, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        calendar1.set(Calendar.MONTH, calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        calendar1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        calendar1.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        calendar1.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ReminderService.class);
        intent.setAction(String.valueOf(id));
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar1.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);

        Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

My **Manifest.xml**

```
    <receiver android:name=".service.ReminderService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

No notification are comes to actionbar
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Please share ReminderService.class
you must have the notification settings complete to trigger this place.

```
<receiver android:name=".ReminderService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

My method is triggered here and it doesn't accept service per

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIMEZONE_CHANGED" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: ReminderService,class is fine, no issue at there
I have facing that no notification comes
While using instant Notification, It works
but at specific time , it does not

Answer (score 0):

Make below changes to your receiver in **Manifest.xml**

```
<receiver
            android:name=".service.ReminderService"
            android:process=":remote"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true" />
```

Create and display notification inside *onReceive()* method of **ReminderService** class as shown below.

```
public class ReminderService extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "");
        wl.acquire();

        //Put your code here to create notification

        wl.release();
    }
}
```

Add below permission in your **Manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```